# React Native Android App Error Close Internet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

Me build file `.apk` in Android then install file app `.apk` in my phone, I close Internet then open app. Then I see error I don't go to my app, please see image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Need more details than this if the app was written by you better post the code as well.

Comment: Please check View error log for details then you know what exactly going on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `expo`, it requires your computer and your phone to be on the same wireless network. See [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#running-your-react-native-application).

> **Running your React Native application**
>
> Install the Expo client app on your iOS or Android phone and connect to the same wireless network as your computer. Using the Expo app, scan the QR code from your terminal to open your project.

Comment: i build file apk. and install in phone then close internet open app it show image